# vimtex: fully indent a '{ ... }' block

Tags: indentation, plugin-vimtex

Concerning indent in `vimtex`, it has some settings controlling indenting of delimiters, the option seems to be `g:vimtex_indent_delims`. However, I would like to not only indent the text between opening and closing braces, but also the braces themselves, leading to a layout like

```
\cs_new:Npn \__hook_parse_dot_label:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      {
        \msg_expandable_error:nn { hooks } { empty-label }
        \__hook_currname_or_default:
      }
      {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1} { . }
          { \__hook_currname_or_default: }
          { \__hook_parse_dot_label:w #1 ./ \s__hook_mark }
      }
  }
```

(this is example code taken from the `lthooks` package.)
So additional to the usual indenting of the lines in the `{...}` block, also the braces themselves should be indented.

From what I can see, there is, however, no such option in `g:vimtex_indent_delims`.

**How can I achieve such an indent in `vimtex`? Is there some other place in the documentation with aprropriate settings you can refer me to?**

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I would add that using = is lacking in general. Perhaps there is a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I can see, there is, however, no such option in g:vimtex_indent_delims.

Correct. **VimTeX does not support this style of indentation.** There is a semi related option `g:vimtex_indent_delims.close_indented` that allows to keep the closing delimiter indented, but there is no option to add indent to the opening delimiter.

I do not plan to add support for this, either. I find it quite hard to write good and robust indentation scripts, and I believe the current indentation of VimTeX is quite good and robust. Adding support for what you ask for would possibly be very hard to do in a robust manner. Feel free to prove me wrong by submitting a pull request with a proof of concept - I'll be happy to accept it if I believe it works well without breaking any current behaviour.